# How to ask iOS for more background execution time with beginBackgroundTask on React Native application

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native

I need all of the execution time iOS can give to the application while it is not on the foreground / active. Most of the applications are suspended as soon as they're moved to the background state, but it is possible to request more execution time on background with 
`beginBackgroundTaskWithName:expirationHandler:` or
`beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:`. Even though the system might suspend or terminate the app if needed, this extra background execution time might extend up to three minutes.

The process seems straightforward on native iOS applications, but I have problems making a Native Module for React Native application that can start/finish these background tasks.

[This article](http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2014/11/13/extending-background-ranging-on-ios.html) explains very similar case where system is asked for more background execution time to range beacons.

My goal is to ask for execution time in a similar manner on the Javascript code in React Native by using a native module for iOS.

I am able to get simpler native modules work with React Native by using the methods described in [the documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios.html).

I couldn't get the calls to the UIApplication `beginBackgroundTaskWithName` or `endBackgroundTask` with `RCT_EXPORT_METHOD()` duo to the references to the background task in question.

I have also tried to just export the methods of code in the article above is this manner, but it obviously does not work.

```
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
#import "BackgroundIOS.h"
#import <React/RCTLog.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@implementation BackgroundIOS

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE();

static BOOL _inBackground;
static _backgroundTask = nil;


RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didDetermineState:(CLRegionState)state forRegion:(CLRegion *)region)
{
  if (_inBackground) {
    [self extendBackgroundRunningTime];
  }
}

RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application)
{
  [self extendBackgroundRunningTime];
  _inBackground = YES;
}

RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application)
{
  _inBackground = NO;
}

RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(extendBackgroundRunningTime) {
  if (_backgroundTask != UIBackgroundTaskInvalid) {
    // if we are in here, that means the background task is already running.
    // don't restart it.
    return;
  }
  NSLog(@"Attempting to extend background running time");

  __block Boolean self_terminate = YES;

  _backgroundTask = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithName:@"DummyTask" expirationHandler:^{
    NSLog(@"Background task expired by iOS");
    if (self_terminate) {
      [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:_backgroundTask];
      _backgroundTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    }
  }];

  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    NSLog(@"Background task started");

    while (true) {
      NSLog(@"background time remaining: %8.2f", [UIApplication sharedApplication].backgroundTimeRemaining);
      [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1];
    }

  });
}

@end
```

EDIT:

It seems like setting up the methods like this could work with the calls from JS:

BackgroundIOS.h:

```
#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface BackgroundIOS : NSObject <RCTBridgeModule>

@property UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier backgroundUpdateTask;

@end
```

BackgroundIOS.m:

```
#import "BackgroundIOS.h"
#import <React/RCTLog.h>

@implementation BackgroundIOS

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE();

RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(beginBackgroundTask){
  NSLog(@"Background time in total: %f",[[UIApplication sharedApplication] backgroundTimeRemaining]);
  [self beginBackgroundUpdateTask];
}

RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(endBackgroundTask){
  [self endBackgroundUpdateTask];
  NSLog(@"Background task ended.");
}

- (void) beginBackgroundUpdateTask
{
  self.backgroundUpdateTask = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
    [self endBackgroundUpdateTask];
  }];
}

- (void) endBackgroundUpdateTask
{
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask: self.backgroundUpdateTask];
  self.backgroundUpdateTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
}

@end
```